# Clicking a file that is executable in KDE's Dolphin file browser will not open it for editing

Tags: linux, rhel, kde, dolphin

Even though I associate the file with a text editor, say gedit, it still won't open if I click/double click it in Dolphin. It does open will if I do the same thing using Nautilus. KDE will open it for editing if the execute permission is removed, or if I right click and select "Open With" >> gedit. Is this a known bug with older KDE versions? I'm using KDE version 4.x.

Is there a workaround/hack for this? I've tried editing the file type properties as follows: right click on file >> Properties >> left click "File Type Options" >> gedit >> Edit >>  Application >> Command >> xterm -e gedit, but this still doesn't work.

Comment: I think you'd normally get a prompt asking whether you want to execute or open it (If not, there is a chance that you're actually running it instead). There is a do not ask again option. You might have opted for that at some point... Try to check dolphin settings -> general -> confirmations -> opening executeable -> always ask.

Comment: @rudib I only have the following three options in the Confirmations tab:Moving files or folders to trash, Deleting files or folders, Closing windows with multiple tabs.

Comment: it should be a dropdown though - it must be set to something. (unless you have a on older version perhaps?) It should be the bottommost setting in that tab. I wonder what it's set to if you have it.